# Django Custom Template tag to check model's field

Tags: python, django

I have a model that will be displayed in a ListView.  One of the fields in the model is category which has 3 choices.  When I display the template, I want to be able to tell between the 3 categories.  I considered overriding get_context_data() to add a context for each category by getting all the objects and filtering them.

Would that be a better approach than a custom template tag?

And even if it is, assuming I still want to create the custom template tag to accomplish this, how would I write it?  I know how to write custom tags, but I am unsure how to write one such as this.

Only idea I can come up with is to create a tag something like:

```
@register.simple_tag(name="is_cat1", takes_context=True)
def is_cat1(self, context):
    objs = context['object_list']
    if (MyModel.objects.filter(category__icontains="Cat1") in objs):
        objs = MyModel.objects.filter(category__icontains="Cat1")
    return objs
```

Could anyone provide an example of such a filter that deals with models like this?  As well as answer my question as to whether it would be better to use context?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot call models from template tags. You have ajax calls for this.

Comment: I am starting to realize that context objects are the only solution, what do you mean by AJAX for this?

Comment: Not for this, but in the template

Comment: I mean can you give me an example of an AJAX call in a template for accessing a model? LIke you mentioned?

Comment: AJAX is a javascript concept - It's not really part of django templates. Using AJAX you can send a query to a server and return back the object (normally json) and use this json to populate other html entities. Read more here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AJAX is the correct solution.  Such an operation doesn't fit with Django's framework and intended use.